# padding and max-width of buttons in Firefox

Tags: button, css

I am trying to style some buttons and I am trying to both limit the width of my buttons and have some horizontal padding, so there is some space between the text and the border.

I have therefore applied the following CSS to my class:

```css
.class1 {
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 0 20px;
    max-width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLjJa/) for an example.

My problem is that when the text is too long, Firefox (latest version: 22) does not respect the left padding anymore and make the text stick to the left border, as one can see in the middle button in this screenshot:

[image: Result in Firefox]

When Chrome still respect the left padding:

[image]

Is there some way I can make Firefox behaves the same way as Chrome and IE10 here?

Some things I have determined:

- IE10 behaves the same way as Chrome, so I think it's a Firefox problem.
- If I replace buttons with spans, it works, but of course I need buttons. I would like to avoid using `<a>` if it is not necessary, since it is not semantically correct.
- Changing the `box-sizing` property or resetting `-moz-focus-inner`, does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this 'hack':

```
.class1::-moz-focus-inner {

    padding: 0px 20px;

}
```

You have to remove the padding in Firefox to prevent double padding.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {

    .class1 {

        padding: 0px;

    }

}
```

(It works for me in FF 22, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLjJa/2/))

Comment: You're right, I can indeed do something with that approach. Thank you very much.

Comment: Wait, it's more complicated. For this to work, I have to remove the padding in the `class1` rule or it will have twice the amount of padding for the short ones. But then it will not have any padding in other browsers, only in Firefox. Do you have something that can work for both?

Comment: I'll edit my answer! Keep in mind that this tricks may **not** be future proof. You should check them in new browsers.